# How to display all birthday days till 2025 starting from originating year

Tags: python-3.x

```
from datetime import date,time,timedelta
d = int(input("Enter the year:"))
while (d < 2025):
    d += 1
    dt = date(month = 4, day = 6, year = d)
    print(d,":",dt.strftime("%A"))
```

**I have coded to get all my birthday days till 2025.But how to start with originating year**

**output:
Enter the year: 1997
1998 : Monday
1999 : Tuesday
2000 : Thursday
2001 : Friday
2002 : Saturday
2003 : Sunday
2004 : Tuesday
2005 : Wednesday
2006 : Thursday
2007 : Friday
2008 : Sunday
2009 : Monday
2010 : Tuesday
2011 : Wednesday
2012 : Friday
2013 : Saturday
2014 : Sunday
2015 : Monday
2016 : Wednesday
2017 : Thursday
2018 : Friday
2019 : Saturday
2020 : Monday
2021 : Tuesday
2022 : Wednesday
2023 : Thursday
2024 : Saturday
2025 : Sunday**

Comment: move `d += 1` after the `print`

Comment: Thank you @gogaz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try by increasing the count after you're printing the date ?

```
from datetime import date,time,timedelta
d = int(input("Enter the year:"))
while (d < 2025):
    dt = date(month = 4, day = 6, year = d)
    print(d,":",dt.strftime("%A"))  # print current year 
    d += 1  # then increment to +1
```